# В блочной верстке футер не прижимается к низу сайта и колонки разной высоты

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="header"><p class="hello">Привет участникам соревнований!</p></div>
    <div class="menu"><p class="types"> Виды спорта:</p>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="content">
        <img src="img/photo.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="football">Футбол</p>
            <p>Футбол-командный вид спорта, в котором целью является забить мяч в ворота соперника ногами илидругими частями тела (кроме рук) большее окличество раз, чем команда соперника.<br>
            <br>Есть 17 официальных правил игры, каждое из которых содержит список оговорок и руководящих принципов. Эти правила предназначены для применения  на всех уровнях<br> футбола, хотя есть некоторые изменения для таких групп, как юниоры, взрослые, женщины, и люди с ограниченными физическими возможностями. Законы очень часто формулировлаись в общих чертах, которые позволяют упростить применения взависимости от характера игры.которые позволяют упростить применения взависимости от характера игры.которые позволяют упростить применения взависимости от характера игры.которые позволяют упростить применения взависимости от характера игры.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"><p class="participation"> Главное не победа, а участие!</p></div>
 </div>
```

```
  <style>
   body{
       margin:0;
       height:100%;
   }
   .container{
       min-height: 100%;
       width:100%;
       margin:0 auto;
   }
   .header{
    background-color:#add8e6;
    height:50px;
    }
    .footer{
    background-color:#add8e6;
    height:70px;
    clear:both;
    }
    .menu{
    height:550px;
    width:250px;
    background-color:#f0e68c;
    float:left;
    }
    .content{
       margin-left:250px;
       background:url(img/ball.png) repeat-y right;
        
    }
    img{
        float:left;
        margin-top:60px;
        padding: 20px 20px 10px;
        
    }
    .hello{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color:blue;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:0;
    
}
.participation{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color:blue;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 5px;
}
.football{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    padding:0 250px 0 0;
    
    
} 
p{
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top:40px;
    padding:0 20px 0;
    
}
li{
    font-size: 20px; 
}
.types{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin-top:20px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ежели не нужна поддержка старых браузеров (например Internet Explorer), то лучше все сделать на `flex`-элементах.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:    -moz-flex;
  display:         flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
     -moz-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#header {
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
     -moz-flex: 0 1 auto;
          flex: 0 1 auto;
  background: red;
}

#footer {
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
     -moz-flex: 0 1 auto;
          flex: 0 1 auto;
  background: blue;
}

#main {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:    -moz-flex;
  display:         flex;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
     -moz-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: yellow;
}

#sidebar {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:    -moz-flex;
  display:         flex;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 200px;
     -moz-flex: 0 0 200px;
          flex: 0 0 200px;
  background: green;
}

#mainbar {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:    -moz-flex;
  display:         flex;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
     -moz-flex: 1 1 auto;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: yellow;
}

#header, #footer,
#mainbar, #sidebar {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div id="mainbar">Mainbar</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```